# Isomorphism in the case of real symmetric matrices

Tags: matrices, spectra

I'm looking for clarification of the following problem: it's known that determining which graphs are uniquely determined by their spectra is in general a very hard problem. 
But what about more general problem - real symmetric square matrices? 
1) Do we have the same problem when two cospectral matrices can be non-isomorphic?
And a related question: 2) is there any simple method to test isomorphism of two arbitrary real symmetric square matrices?
Many Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.